# Transferring a Java Exception stacktrace between application tiers

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-ee, rmi

In our organization we have Java EE multi-tier applications, each tier in a physical weblogic cluster.

Right now, when an exception occurs in the backend tier (lowest tier), our framework only transfers the "exception message" to upper tiers, not the entire stack trace, for network bandwith reasons.

We want more detailed information about the exception in upper tiers, but we need to keep the message small (as few KB as possible).

How can we address this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Generate the full stack trace and zip it.  Any redundant information (from nested stack traces) will compress very well.

Why are you concerned about network bandwidth?  Aren't these very rare?